# Regex: Select all words that doesn't start with letter "p"

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I must use regex to select all words that doesn't start with letter "p". For example:

`book, laptop, promise`

So, the regex formula must select only `book, laptop`

My formula doesn't work, don't know why:

FIND: `\b(?!p)\w+\b`  **OR**  `\b(?!p){1}\w+\b`  **OR**  `\b(?![p])\w+\b`

My formulas selects also some single letters, but not just words `\w+`

Comment: I commend to your attention a [Regular Expression Cheat Sheet](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html). There are other such out there on the web; this one appeared relatively compact.

Comment: yes, I know that regex page. But doesn't give me any solution to my case...

Comment: regex101.com is also a very good site to test regular expressions

Comment: Where did you find these particular regexes and why do you think that they *should* work?

Comment: my friends, I made myself those regex, of course. And I know all those pages. But I made 3 formulas, and does't work good. Can you give a much better solution?

Comment: My formulas are almost good. But if I have in the text simple letters like `b`, or `w` will also find those. So, I need to find only words, not letters different from `p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a negated character class (`[^]`).

This would work:

```
\b[^p\s]\w+
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b[^p\s]\w+
\b          #word boundary, anchor to the beginning of a word
  [^ ]      #negated character class, matches any character except specified
    p       #literally "p"
     \s     #any whitespace character
      \w    #matches any word character
        +   #quantifies previous expression between 1 and infinity times
```

Note that unfortunately this doesn't match any single character words, for example "I". You could modify the expression to `\b[^p\s]\w+|(?<=\s)\b\w\b`.

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/3Yj3hi/1)

Comment: great answer, thanks a lot !

Comment: I also think about `\b(?![^p\s])\w+\b`  But your first formula is the best of !! Your second regex also finds letter `p`

Comment: @JustMe You are double negating there, your solution would only match on words starting with p. By removing the `^`, `\b(?![p\s])\w+\b` would work.

Comment: almost works... But It also finds the simple letter `w` in the text.

Answer (score 2):

You regex works fine for me, you just have to match words with more than 1 letter:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `\b(?!p)\w{2,}`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b          # word boundary, make sure we haven't a word character before
(?!p)       # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't the letter "p" after
\w{2,}      # 2 or more word character, make sure we don't match single letter
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]